# Generic word for religious establishment

Tags: word-choice, religion

I need a word to describe any community that is religious. For example, a Church Group or Temple Youth Group. Would Religous Institution be correct?

Edit: As single word would probably be impossible, 2 or 3 word phrases would also work.

Comment: *sect*, *cult*, *coven*, *order*,... (just kidding).

Comment: Cannot think of any single word that conveys all off these permutations. Those two together do seem to convey what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the word "community" would suffice. You can also use "church" in a multi-faith sense although many readers may identify that word specifically with Christianity.

Comment: That would be good, but the problem is I am using it in a context with other groups that are specified as a type of "Community"